# How to use cases on order by in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

If t_date(column_name) is Today's date then

```
select * from `schedules` 
ORDER BY available_seats <= 0 , STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p');
```

Else

```
select * from `schedules`
ORDER BY (available_seats <= 0 && (STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') >= TIME(NOW()))), (STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') <= TIME(NOW())), STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p');
```

END

Query 1 is for t_date = DATE(now())

Query 2 is for t_date != DATE(now())

How can i make it in a single query with condition on order by??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM `schedules` 
ORDER BY 
available_seats <= 0 ,
CASE WHEN t_date <> CURRENT_DATE()  AND (available_seats <= 0 && (STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') >= TIME(NOW())))
THEN
(STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') <= TIME(NOW()))
WHEN t_date = CURRENT_DATE() 
THEN STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p')
ELSE STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') END,
STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p')
```

Comment: @M khalid available_seats <= 0 , STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') Here SQL Syntax Error is coming.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid SELECT *  FROM `schedules`  ORDER BY CASE WHEN t_date = CURRENT_DATE()  THEN  available_seats <= 0 , STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') ELSE (available_seats <= 0 && (STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') >= TIME(NOW()))), (STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') <= TIME(NOW())), STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') END Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') ELSE (available_seats <= 0 && (STR_TO_DAT' at line 6 0.000 sec

Answer (score 0):

In English, what are you actually trying to get your order by and maybe adjust your question for clarification...

However, I think you might want all "available_seats" values less or equal to zero FIRST, THEN based on the date from today.  If that is the case, you may want something like..

```
order by 
   case when available_seats <= 0 then 1 else 2 end,
   STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p')
```

But it should all be possible in a simple single query, but there is no context to what the seats, dates are for and what you want and why...  Are you looking for something like "Sold-out" events sorted to top of list, then based on date of event with closest coming event listed first?

The case/when I have above basically puts any returned records that have available seats <= 0 in the first order sequence regardless of actual 0 or negative value... Then, anything else, if 1 seat or 1000 seats left are sorted after.  The SECOND part of the order by is just on the date_time field itself.  Since the order by is regardless of the "formatted" column that might be retrieved in the field list, I am just ordering by the date/based conversion as you had.